# Latex Table all along the page

Tags: latex, tex

[image: Tabl]

I am looking to have a similar style of the table in the picture. I just do not know the code would make it in this way.

I know how to make table, but I do not know how would I make them in this way.

Comment: That looks like a table created with the [booktabs package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple answer to this question since it would take quite some time to create this entire table, which is a large commitment :-)  If you're committed to it, it's worthwhile to understand, but you may want to begin with what you know and build off of it.  Is there a particular part of this table that you are struggling with?  Can you give us an example of how far you've gotten that we can expand on?

Here are a couple useful references that could help you get started:

- [A bit more about tables](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Tables)
- [A more advanced approach with different packages](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf)

I'm sure there are many others.  Once you get started, try posting where you get stuck.  I hope this helps!